# Grub2 lost in new Linux distro install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2

So, I really need some help. Recently I was using a dual boot machine on the same hard drive. I had Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.

When I installed Ubuntu on top of my Windows install, I didn't have to install the Grub bootloader. I just created my partitions /, /home and /swap and installed. After that the grub was already working and I could switch between OS's.

So, I wasn't really liking the Gnome desktop and the distro was kind of lagging, so I decided to switch to another one. After some researching I decided to go with OpenSUSE 13.2. So I went on installing, I replaced my old partitions /, /home with new formatted ones and took the existing /swap one. After that I installed OpenSUSE, and for my surprise after reboot my machine would go to a Grub2 shell.

I tried reinstalling openSUSE four times. One of them was with the partitioning suggested by the installer. Still it couln't boot on linux, I was always going to the grub shell. (note that I could boot in Windows 8.1)

After some research I managed to find and boot my linux installation within the grub shell.
I followed this steps: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/

So now I could boot again on linux, but whenever I would restart my computer I had to do all those steps again.

Today I replaced openSUSE with elementary-os luna (bad font rendering), but I still got the same problem with grub. After logging in on luna I tried updating grub and installing it by these commands:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda1
```

Updating works fine, but the install command gives me back this warning:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a partitionless disk or to a partition.  This is a BAD idea..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

So now I don't know what to do. I sure could follow some tutorials and try a lot of things, but for what I know it is not really safe to mess with grub commands.

All I want is to restore the bootloader so I could boot on windows or linux.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, you are trying to install in a partition: `/dev/sda1`. It is much more common to install in the MBR by using `/dev/sda`.

That is actually what is recommended at the end of the tutorial you refer to:

```
...
done
# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```